# React Native Error : You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed natively on your iOS project by calling firebase.storage()

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm facing Error in iOS and android is working fine. Error: `Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed natively on your iOS project by calling firebase.storage().

Ensure you have either linked the module or added it to your projects Podfile.`

Pod File

```
    require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'App' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  
 
    rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
    pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
    pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'GoogleUtilities'

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"]
      # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
     )
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'react-native-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

  target 'APPTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
```

kindly help me out to fix this

Comment: What is your react-native version?

Comment: @DánielBoros react-native version is 0.63.4

Answer (score 0):

Hence your react native version is bigger than 0.60.1, linking is made automatically when you build your project. You need to run these commands at root folder of your project.

```
cd ios/
pod install --repo-update
cd ..
npx react-native run-ios
```